# Como resolver problema no C# ao executar o comando ".ExecuteReader()" e é retornado erro?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando executar o comando "ExecuteReader()" e sempre se retorna o erro "threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException".

A ideia dessa parte do código é:

1. Abrir um arquivo ".xls" (Está funcionando)
2. Pegar o CNPJ da empresa dentro do arquivo (Está funcionando)
3. Pesquisar se essa empresa já está cadastrada **(O erro acontece aqui)**
4. Pesquisar se a nota (relacionada a essa empresa) já foi cadastrada
5. Colocar os dados do arquivo ".xls" relacionados a essa nota, em uma tabela temporária.

Como eu falei, sou novo com a linguagem C# e ainda não consegui compreender bem como funciona essa tipo de pesquisa.

Poderiam me ajudar com isso?

Colocarei essa parte do código aqui.

Desde já, grato.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Importador_SCI.Classes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Importador_SCI.Classes
{
    class clsImporta
    {
        public OleDbConnection _olecon;
        private OleDbCommand _oleCmd;
        private String _StringConexao;
        private String NomeCopia;
        private String Diretorio;
        private String Planilha;
        private int DeuErro;
        private String Documento;
        private String CNPJ;
        private int StatusGravacao;
        private String CodEmpresa;

        //Função de Importação do arquivo para as tabelas temporárias
        public bool ImportaSCI(string CaminhoArquivo)
        {

            //////////////////////////////////
            //      Status de Gravação      //
            //------------------------------//
            //  0 = Tudo OK para importar   //
            //  1 = Nota já importada       //
            //  2 = Empresa não cadastrada  //
            //  3 = Produto não cadastrado  //
            //////////////////////////////////

            //Cria uma cópia temporária do arquivo para que esta seja importada
            Diretorio = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(CaminhoArquivo);
            NomeCopia = "#Tmp_Copia_Imp.xls";
            System.IO.File.Copy(CaminhoArquivo, Diretorio + "\\" + NomeCopia, true);

            //Preenche Variável de conexão
            _StringConexao = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=False';", Diretorio + "\\" + NomeCopia);

            //Zera os erros
            DeuErro = 0;

            //Abre o arquivo
            AbreConexao();

            try
            {
                //Pega o Nome da primeira Planilha
                DataTable dt_Plan = _olecon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt_Plan.Rows)
                {
                    Planilha = dr[2].ToString();
                    break;
                }

                //Faz pesquisa na primeira planilha
                this._oleCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + Planilha + "]";

                OleDbDataReader reader = this._oleCmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Verifica se existem linhas para serem importadas
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    //Cria a tabela temporária 'Tmp_NotasEntradas'
                    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

                    sql.Append("CREATE TABLE #Tmp_NotasEntradas (");
                    sql.Append("StatusGravacao [int] NOT NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[nNF] [nvarchar](9) NOT NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[natOp] [nvarchar](60) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[cod_empresa] [int] NULL,");
                    sql.Append("[Operação] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[contCFOP] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[indPag] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[mod] [smallint] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[serie] [nvarchar](3) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[dEmi] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[dSaiEnt] [smalldatetime] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[hSaiEnt] [time](7) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[DataLancamento] [smalldatetime] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[tpNF] [smallint] NULL,");
                    sql.Append("[Condição] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[Transportadora] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[status] [tinyint] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[modFrete] [bit] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[qVol] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[esp] [nvarchar](50) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[nVol] [nvarchar](60) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[pesoL] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,");
                    sql.Append("[pesoB] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vICMS] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vBC] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vBCST] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vST] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vProd] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vFrete] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vSeg] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vDesc] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vII] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vIPI] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vPIS] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vCOFINS] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vOutro] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vNF] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vRetPIS] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vRetCofins] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vretCSLL] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vBCIRRF] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vRetIRRF] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vBCRetPrev] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vRetPrev] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[observacoes] [nvarchar](255) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[arquivo] [xml] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[chaveAcesso] [varchar](60) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[infAdFisco] [nvarchar](255) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[class1] [char](1) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[ObservacaoEBS] [nvarchar](255) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[xmlCancelado] [xml] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[NumeroOC] [nvarchar](50) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[IndustrializadoPorOP] [bit] NOT NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[NotaOperacaoTriangular] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[EmpresaIndustrializadora] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[CreditoICMS] [numeric](10, 2) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[Aliquota] [numeric](10, 4) NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[ICMSSNST] [int] NULL, ");
                    sql.Append("[vICMSST] [numeric](10, 2) NULL ");
                    sql.Append(")");


                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), clsConecta.Con);

                    try
                    {
                        //Executa o comando de criação da tabela temporária 'Tmp_NotasEntradas'
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //Percorre o arquivo verificando se a empresa está cadastrada e se a nota para essa empresa já foi importada
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader[10].ToString() != "Documento" && reader[10].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                Documento = reader[10].ToString();
                                CNPJ = reader[7].ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "").Replace("/", "");

                                //Pesquisa se a empresa está cadastrada, pelo CNPJ
                                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COD_EMPRESA FROM Empresas WHERE CNPJ = '" + CNPJ.ToString() + "'";

                                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                                if (dr.FieldCount == 0)
                                {
                                    StatusGravacao = 2;
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                   **O ERRO ACONTECE NESSA LINHA ABAIXO**
                                    //Pega o Código da Empresa
                                    CodEmpresa = dr["COD_EMPRESA"].ToString();

                                    //Verifica se a nota já foi importada
                                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS QNT " + 
                                                      "FROM NotasEntradas N " +
                                                           "INNER JOIN Empresas E ON N.cod_empresa = E.COD_EMPRESA" +
                                                      "WHERE N.nNF = " + Documento.ToString() +
                                                            "AND E.CNPJ = '" + CNPJ.ToString() + "'";

                                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                                    if (dr.FieldCount > 0)
                                    {
                                        StatusGravacao = 1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //Adiciona essa nota na tabela temporária
                                        StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
                                        sqlQuery.Append("INSERT INTO #Tmp_NotasEntradas () VALUES (");


                                        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery.ToString();
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }



                                //Insere os produtos relacionados com as notas na tabela 'Tmp_Produtos'

                                //Insere as faturas relacionadas com as notas na tabela 'Tmp_Faturas'

                                //Se tudo ocorreu bem, insere todos os dados das tabelas temporárias nas oficiais
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao se tentar criar a tabela temporária 'Tmp_NotasEntradas'.\n\n Mensagem de Erro: \n" + ex.Message, "SISTOP - Erro no Carregamento", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        //Atribui False para o retorno
                        DeuErro = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("O arquivo escolhida não possue nenhuma linha de informação válida para ser importada", "SISTOP - Erro no Carregamento", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    //Atribui False para o retorno
                    DeuErro = 1;
                }

                reader.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro na importação do arquivo.\n\n Mensagem de Erro: \n" + ex.Message, "SISTOP - Erro no Carregamento", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                //Atribui False para o retorno
                DeuErro = 1;
            }

            //Fecha arquivo
            FechaConexao();

            //Exclue o arquivo Cópia
            System.IO.File.Delete(Diretorio + "\\" + NomeCopia);


            //Ao final, retorna FALSE caso tenha ocorrido algum erro ou TRUE caso tenha dado certo
            if (DeuErro == 1)
            {
                DeuErro = 0;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seu código está desnecessariamente complicado, não precisa disso tudo. Não parece precisar de uma tabela temporária no banco, armazene em memória... você pode colocar quebra de linha na string usando um @ antes do primeiro "... `deuErro = 0/1` utilize um boolean... `StatusGravacao` utilize um Enum... faça um método para ler o arquivo, outro para buscar a empresa. Quanto ao erro específico, aponte qual linha ocorre, e qual a mensagem da Exception.

Comment: A mensagem de erro é essa "'dr["COD_EMPRESA"]' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException" {"Tentativa inválida de leitura quando não existem dados."}. Quanto a armazenar na memória, ao invés da tabela temporária, irei pesquisar como posso fazer. Obrigado sobre a explicação da quebra de linha. Quanto as variáveis, não tem problema como estão, pois é temporária essa forma mesmo.

Comment: sobre o erro, só faltou dar um `dr.Read()` para que o reader aponte para o primeiro registro, guardar em memória, só usar um List<T> onde T é o tipo do seu objeto.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Desculpe pela falta de experiência nessa linguagem. Passei um longo tempo pesquisando e não havia entendido o que poderia estar errado.

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar, todo mundo teve o dia 1, rsrs mas recomendo dar uma olhada aqui na comunidade tem muito material mostrando como elaborar as perguntas, apesar de já ter solucionado seu problema, é ruim elaborar uma resposta com uma pergunta que não está clara, tente colocar apenas a parte relevante. Bons estudos

Comment: Além do `.Read()`, verifique se o `dr` possui linhas antes de tentar ler e atribuir os valores, existe a propriedade `HasRows`